# Raws into String under particular conditions

Tags: t-sql

basing on code provided below I would need to achieve Desired Table:
[image]

The rule is:

for each Ticker to return ErrorCode chain/cluster where cluster is being generated only if time difference between cosecutive occurings of errors is less than 10 minutes.

Under other post I was asking for assist regarding simpler version of that task: error chain is generated for each day seperately. The best option (working in very effective way) there were STUFF + For XML Path.

Can we use it for this - more complex - task somehow? Or alteratively it should be achieved with cursors?

I would appreciate any suggestions on that.

Regards,
Arek

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    [Ticket] INT,
    [ErrorCode] CHAR(1),
    [Date] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES
(1, 'A', '01.07.2018  10:00:00'),
(1, 'B', '01.07.2018  10:02:00'),
(1, 'C', '01.07.2018  10:08:00'),
(1, 'A', '01.07.2018  10:30:09'),
(1, 'B', '01.07.2018  10:50:00'),
(1, 'D', '01.07.2018  10:55:00'),
(1, 'D', '01.07.2018  15:55:00'),
(1, 'D', '02.07.2018  10:55:00'),
(2, 'A', '20.10.2018  15:00:00'),
(2, 'C', '20.10.2018  17:00:00'),
(2, 'C', '20.10.2018  17:07:00'),
(2, 'A', '21.10.2018  09:00:00');
```

Comment: What should happen if there additionally is a record `(1, 'X', '2018-07-01 10:11:00')` in the input? Are there two rows `(1, 'A/B/C')` and `(1 'B/C/X')` in the result or one row `(1, 'A/B/C/X')` or something else?

Comment: Additionaly record X will be added to first string : 1: A / B /C / X. As long as time difference between two subsequent records is less than 10 minutes it should be included in the same chain.Difference longer than 10 minutes breaks the chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use a conditional flag, and then aggregate this flag via the window function sum() over

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
                Select * 
                      ,Flg = case when datediff(MINUTE,lag(Date,1) over (Partition by Ticket Order By Date) , Date) > 10  then 1 else 0 end
                 From  @table1 
), cte1 as (
                Select *
                      ,Grp = sum(Flg) over (Partition By Ticket Order by Date)
                 From  cte
)
Select Distinct 
       Grp
      ,Ticket
      ,Cluster =  Stuff((Select '/' +ErrorCode From cte1 Where Ticket=A.Ticket and Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte1 A
 Order by Ticket,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Grp Ticket  Cluster
0   1       A/B/C
1   1       A
2   1       B/D
3   1       D
4   1       D
0   2       A
1   2       C/C
2   2       A
```

> **EDIT - Requested Update**

```
;with cte as (
                Select * 
                      ,Flg = case when datediff(MINUTE,lag(Date,1) over (Partition by Ticket Order By Date) , Date) > 10  then 1 else 0 end
                 From  @table1 
), cte1 as (
                Select *
                      ,Grp = sum(Flg) over (Partition By Ticket Order by Date)
                 From  cte
)
Select Distinct 
       Grp
      ,Ticket
      ,LastDate = convert(date,max(Date) over (Partition By Ticket,Grp))
      ,Times    = Stuff((Select ',' +format(Date,'HH:mm') From cte1 Where Ticket=A.Ticket and Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
      ,Cluster  =  Stuff((Select '/' +ErrorCode From cte1 Where Ticket=A.Ticket and Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte1 A
 Order by Ticket,Grp
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT - Tweak Performance**

By migrating the `XML/STUFF` to a final/reduced set, you may get a little more performance.   The string aggregation is a heavy hit to begin with.  We're just reducing the number of calls.

Another option is to use TEMP tables rather than CTEs.

```
;with cte as (
                Select * 
                      ,Flg = case when datediff(MINUTE,lag(Date,1) over (Partition by Ticket Order By Date) , Date) > 10  then 1 else 0 end
                 From  @table1 
), cte1 as (
                Select *
                      ,Grp = sum(Flg) over (Partition By Ticket Order by Date)
                 From  cte
), cte2 as (
                Select Distinct 
                       Grp
                      ,Ticket
                      ,LastDate = convert(date,max(Date) over (Partition By Ticket,Grp))
                 From  cte1 A
)
Select *
      ,Times    = Stuff((Select ',' +format(Date,'HH:mm') From cte1 Where Ticket=A.Ticket and Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
      ,Cluster  =  Stuff((Select '/' +ErrorCode From cte1 Where Ticket=A.Ticket and Grp=A.Grp For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte2 A
 Order by Ticket,Grp
```

> **EDIT - Step-By-Step**

cte Generates 
Notice Flg is 1 or 0

[image]

cte1 Generates

[image]

cte2 Generates
Notice Grp is a Running Total of Flag

[image]

Comment: Hi John, works very impresive, thank you! Have to get familar with that flag functionality. And what should be done if two additional columns would very handy: 1.column with date of the last error code from the cluster? 2. string column with relevant times (only hh:mm) for errors listed within Cluster column? I would appreciate your help on that.

Comment: @ArkadiuszCiesielski See Update.  It will be well worth your time to get comfortable with the window functions...  Also, you could ACCEPT the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: @ArkadiuszCiesielski Updated for times

Comment: Thank you again, how efficient and elegant the code is:) Last question from my side: what kind of index and on which columns of source table should be in your opion created to improve the processing? Now it takes about 10 minuts to return the output for 1k rows what is not impressive.. I have created nonclustered on Ticket and Date but it didn't change anything..

Comment: @ArkadiuszCiesielski The index wouldn't buy you much.  The Flag and Grp are virtual elements.   See EDIT - Tweak.   If not sufficient, you may want to create TEMP tables for more performance.

Comment: OK. I will test it, thank you. And one question, the code [ Select *  ,Flg] is this the conditional flag you mentioned in the answer? What is the full name of functionality so I can find any tutorials on that?

Comment: @ArkadiuszCiesielski Here we are using the window function lag()  to get the datediff in minutes.  If > 10 then the value is 1 otherwise it is 0.   In the next cte we use the window function sum(flag) over ().  This will generate the dynamic Grp.    It may help you visualize it better if  you replace the final query with Select * from cte ... see the results  ... then make the final query Select * from cte1 and then Select * from cte2

Comment: Are you able to recommend me any online tutorial so I can try to understand those dynamic/virtual elements?

Comment: @ArkadiuszCiesielski No tutorials that I can think of.  It is more of a technique.   I added a step-by-step to aid in the visualization.

Comment: Hi John, I need to ask for your support on that. I run the full version of the query(with Times and Last Date) yesterday and had to abort it a while ago after 11 hours of executing:) Can you please propose how it should looks like with temp tables intead of CTE so I can test in in terms of performance?

Comment: Something else is going on here,  I've been at this for decades and I have NEVER seen any query take 11 hours, and we're talking BIG data.   How many rows is your source?

Comment: Hmm. I used your full code (2 additional columns) with no changes and it takes: 12 secs to process 1k raws and .. 13 minutes to process 10k rows. Is that normal? Finally I need to proccess about 500k rows. Can you please suggest anything here?:)